# Как убрать консольное окно на старте без использования winMain?

Tags: visual-studio, qt, консоль, main

Перед появлением графического окна выплывает консольное окно на старте, как от него избавится?
(Без замены main на winMain!)
код main'а следующий:

```
  int main(int _nArgCount, char * _pArgValues[]) {

    QApplication app(_nArgCount, _pArgValues);

    //QMLblock
    QString strQmlPath = "qrc:qml/main.qml";
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    QQmlComponent component(&engine, QUrl(strQmlPath));
    if (component.status() == QQmlComponent::Error) {
        qDebug()<<"Error:"<<component.errorString();
        return app.exec();
    }

    Gui gui(component);
    gui.recreateGui();

    //state machine block
    QStateMachine machine;
    ...
    ...
    ...
   return app.exec();
    }
```

Comment: Visual Studio или не оно?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Именно оно! ...

Comment: @Mira ответил ниже

Comment: @Mira - на правах оффтопика - Qt без QtCreator - это как на велосипеде без педалей.

Comment: @gbg Это отдельная тема, как QT creator сглючил так, что пришлось отказаться от него совсем, за нерешаемостью проблемы.

Comment: @Mira Это как же он ТАК сглючил? IDE - это фактически, продвинутый редактор текстов + компилятор. Компилятор от вижака цепляется к криэйтору за два тыка мышкой, остается проблема в компиляторе. Чтобы напороться на проблему в компиляторе, надо или иметь более чем кривые руки, или мегаталант. У вас что?

Comment: @gbg а он после сборки стал говорить - запустить экзешник мне не хватает прав (10 винда пометила экзешник "щитом" и вообще) ) я пробовала все - и тотальное разрешение прав и переустановку всего чего можно (creator) и в различные места (системный-несистемный диск) и отключение всех возможных uac-брандмауэров и проч. И запуск из под админа...в общем надежды нет  и это вообще можно былоб оформить отдельным вопросом

Comment: @gbg, что такого есть в QT Creator, что он настолько не заменим? Всего лишь IDE, да и то, на мой взгляд, со слабым функционалом

Comment: @PavelParshin как минимум, встроенная документация и чуть более удобные хоткеи.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Из аналогичного вопроса на [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139637/hide-console-of-windows-application) (в переводе):

> В настройках линковщика указать: 
>   `/SUBSYSTEM:windows` 
>   `/ENTRY:mainCRTStartup`

Или использовать следующую `#pragma` в исходном файле с функцией `main`:

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/SUBSYSTEM:windows /ENTRY:mainCRTStartup")
```

Comment: Вы спасли меня!!! Спасибо огромное :)

Comment: WIN32 к сожалению создает некоторое количество ошибок линковки ) потому не актуальный вариант. pragma работает хорошо

Comment: @Mira, извиняюсь, не прав. Согласно документации `WIN32` эквивалентно `/SUBSYSTEM:windows` и это работает с `gcc`.

Comment: и обновленный вариант cmake не прошел: cl : командная строка warning D9002: пропуск неизвестного параметра "/SUBSYSTEM:windows"
1>cl : командная строка warning D9002: пропуск неизвестного параметра "/ENTRY:mainCRTStartup"

Comment: Попробуйте так: `set(CMAKE_CREATE_WIN32_EXE "/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /ENTRY:\"mainCRTStartup\"")`.

Comment: ошибку не выдает, но и консольку не убирает. Ладно, забейте на  флаги )

Answer (score 5):

Если дело происходит в QtCreator, а система сборки - qmake, нужно залезть в файл проекта (`*.pro`) и вышвырнуть оттуда опцию `-console`

Comment: Прошу прощения, не указала IDE - visual studio

Answer (score 3):

По хардкору берете `Detect it Easy` -> `PE` -> `Subsystem` и меняете значение на `02 WINDOWS_GUI`

В `Visual Studio` в настройках проекта убираете `Console` на  `Windows` во вкладке `Linker` или соседней, лень открывать. Если в `Qt Creator`, то как сказали выше.

Comment: Не поленился, залез в студию. Заходите в настройки солюшина `Linker` -> `System` -> и меняете `SubSystem` на `Windows`. Заметьте, что по сути консоль нужна для дебага. При релизе проекта автоматически `subsystem` меняется на `windows`.

Comment: Где поменять на win знаю, а где Detect it easy? Что это?

Comment: @Mira это из области хакинга, не заморачивайтесь.

Comment: @Mira у вас русская VS?

Comment: @Mira зайдите в настройки проекта вашего, в линковщик, потом в система и смените как я описал выше.

Comment: Linker -> system это известный мне путь, требует winMain функцию, а ее параметры не подходят на вход QApp, в этом собственно и вопрос! Как сделать без winMain.

Comment: @Mira отключить console в дебаг режиме?

Comment: Консоль у меня запускается при запуске ехе-шника руками. а не в дебаг режиме.

Comment: У вас скомпилированное приложение в Debug. Может вам показать более детально в скайпе?

Comment: И при компиляции в релизе та же история. Могу показать в скайпе, стучитесь )

Comment: Ну черканите свой скайп, я добавлю вас